# content vertical alignment inside li

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code and I want to align content in `li`-element. I have image and text info in the `li`-element.

I tried `vertical-align: middle` for `li`-element, but it doesn't work

```css
li img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="post-title" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <p class="post-date">March 05, 2015</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="post-title" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <p class="post-date">March 05, 2015</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `li { height: 75px; line-height: 75px; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your HTML slightly and use the `display:table-cell` trick. Flexbox might something to look into as well, thought it's not as widely supported yet.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="post-title" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <p class="post-date">March 05, 2015</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="post-title" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <p class="post-date">March 05, 2015</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li div {  
    height: 200px; /*or whatever you need */
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1xhw8uvb/)